# Adding views to the Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

Is there a way to add custom views to the Django admin app?

To be specific, I would like to be able to switch out the "content" div for custom static content, while preserving the "header" and "footer" divs. This is different than redirecting to a static HTML page, which would not preserve the header and footer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just configure your view as usual (urls.py -> myapp.views) and then extend the admin base template:

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% block content %}
    My content looking like the rest of the admin app.
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thank you, very simple solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small intro http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter17/, I think where is new version, but I think where is nothing changed in concept of extending admin pages.