# Simplest way to add a view to my Django admin UI?

Tags: django, django-admin

What is the simplest way to add a view to my Django (3.2) admin UI?  That is, add a URL `mysite.com/admin/my-view` so that visiting that URL acts like the rest of admin (in particular, requires similar permissions).

There is a whole page on this, but it's not obvious to me how to piece it together.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites says you can add a `get_urls` to your `AdminSite` class.  Okay, so I need my own `AdminSite` class.  And I need to register it in apps, maybe?

I did this:

```
class MyAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        my_urls = [
            path('my-view', self.my_view, name='my-view')
        ]
        return my_urls + urls

    def my_view(self, request):
        # do something ..

admin_site = MyAdminSite(name='my_admin')
```

and this in urls.py:

```
from .admin import admin_site


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin_site.urls),
```

and this in unchanged in `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings:

```
    'django.contrib.admin',
```

But, now it only shows the admin for the one app, instead of for all the apps.  So how do I get it to auto-discover all the apps like it used to?  Or is there a simpler way?

P.S.  There is also [a question on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302470/adding-views-to-the-django-admin), but the answer didn't have enough detail for me to use it.

**EDIT**: I'm reading [Make new custom view at django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49176113/make-new-custom-view-at-django-admin) and [Django (1.10) override AdminSite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40090090/django-1-10-override-adminsite) ..

**EDIT 2**: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52048526) was a hack, but it works for me:

```
from django.contrib.admin import site

admin_site._registry.update(site._registry)
```

I had to update in the right place (the project `urls.py`), perhaps when all the other admin stuff is already loaded.